# what is the circle with the smallest radius that contains the three points $(0,0)$ , $(1,1)$, and $(2,3)$?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, operations-research

How to write a model that gives us a circle with the smallest radius that contain three points $(0,0)$ , $(1,1)$, and $(2,3)$?

I've tried to model this as following:

if $x, y$  be the location and $r$ is radius:

$ Min \ \ x^2+y^2 = r^2$

$ x^2+y^2 \le 0$

$ (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 \le 1$

$ (x-2)^2+(y-3)^2 \le \sqrt 13$

Comment: You sure about that first constraint?

Comment: Are you okay with my solution? @yaodaovang

Comment: I don't really understand the min-notation you were using, but I understood what your question basically meant, but I just want to check if my answer actually is helpful, if not I will delete it.

Comment: @Some Guy I can't see your solution, please add it one more time.

Comment: I deleted it, it was wrong

Answer (score 4):

How about:

min $r^2$ subject to:

$(x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2 \leq r^2$

$(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 \leq r^2$

$(x-2)^2 + (y-3)^2 \leq r^2$

Comment: I think same as you scott that this is the easiest way to solve this

Answer (score 2):

- Consider the points pair-wise, call them $A$ and $B$. Let the other
  point be $C$
- Consider the circle with $AB$ as diameter and check if $C$ is within this circle.

If you consider all three possibilities, you'll find that the line joining $(0, 0)$ and $(2, 3)$ is the diameter of the required circle. The equation of the circle is

$$(x - 1)^2 + (y - \frac{3}{2})^2 = \left(\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2} \right)^2$$

It is easy to verify that the other point $(1,1)$ lies inside the above circle.

Comment: can you explain in more detail @PTDS

Comment: how did you go from the 2nd matrix to the 3rd matrix? can u show me where i can read more about this method?

Comment: I included the result used in this problem.

Comment: The smallest circle containing these three points will have one of the points in its interior, only two on its boundary.

Comment: see my edit @JaapScherphuis

Comment: on my answer that is